# Conencting local machine to remote Domain

Tags: vpn, dns

I'm currently trying to connect my local machine remotely to my server in the office. The objective is to set this machine up as a domain oppose to workstation so it acts the same as if it was in the office.

I've established a successful VPN to the Server with no problems. I tried connecting to the domain using xyz.local however it couldn't find it.

I've then amended the ipv4 settings for the VPN for which the primary and secondary DNS are pointing to what the server gives out. Still no luck.

I've also noticed using **ipconfig /all** the default gateway is 0.0.0.0 ?

I tried disabling the WIFI adapter but that disconnects everything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by setting the primary DNS to the servers IP address!